# how to set latest coockie as header using restAssued

Tags: java, rest-assured

Scenario is like below : 
I have two URL with me
URL1 = https://someurl.com
URL2 (WebService URL) = https://jira/something/j2/projectstatus?projectID=12345

Now if I login to URL1 on chrome with valid usedID/password and if I directly hit the URL2 on second tab of chrome browser. I get some response.

But, if I do not login to URL1 and trying hitting the URL2 on chrome I get response as 
{error: You do not have permission to login; ErrorID:ERROR}

I do not have nay header information for this web service

Plesae suggest how to hit the URL2 using rest assured with cookies as header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set cookie for second request using RestAssured like:

```
Cookie userNameCookie = new Cookie.Builder("username", "some_value")
                .setSecured(true)
                .setComment("some comment")
            .build();
Cookie pwdCookie = new Cookie.Builder("password", "some_value")
                .setSecured(true)
                .setComment("some comment")
            .build();
Cookies cookies = new Cookies(userNameCookie, pwdCookie);

Response response = given().port(port).cookies(cookies).when().get("request URL");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: I will try thi in my local first

Comment: I tried the above solutions and it is working fine to me.

Comment: Just one more questions here : How can we get latest Cookie and then use that cookie to pass it on the web service request.

Comment: Actually if use todays cookie and run the web service tomorrow. it is not working. What is best solution for this ???... How can I get latest cookie and set it for next web service request..???.. Please suggest